# requesting suggestions on using core poll module

Tags: 6, polls

I'm working in Drupal 6.22.I have a peculiar requirement with my poll module as below

- Display the most recent poll block such that anonymous user could
  vote in it.
- Once the user has voted display the vote results block with link to all
  previous polls page.
- In all polls page again display the poll-vote block of the most recent poll
  with links to previous polls.

I'm not expecting a contributed module that fits all my requirement in a tailor made fashion but wish to know if there's any module that would aid me in satisfying some portion or giving better ideas in implementing it. I did my search and found [Poll Enhancements Module](http://drupal.org/project/pollanon) and [Poll Improved Module](http://drupal.org/project/pollim) which sound promising for D7 but are not quite there for D6.

Is there a better option of implementing this than arm twisting the poll module with coding?
If anyone could share their suggestions, ideas or experiences it would be nice...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to get it done with a custom module

Set permission for Anonymous user to vote in poll.

Accomplished the desired with a custom module, used the core poll.module code with its menu callback method for listing poll content ($items['poll']) as an example and implemented customized logic. Used to module_invoke to invoke the block content of the poll module and added it to the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Decisions](http://drupal.org/project/decisions) module in your site. This module depends on [VotingAPI](http://drupal.org/project/votingapi) module. This module have some nice features. I havent tested much but its good module to look at. Good Luck.